# Bad redirect from Omniauth / Devise on Failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

Currently my app is setup to use Omniauth and Devise with Twitter and Facebook. My problem is when a user presses cancel on Twitter or Facebook doesn't authorize it sends me back to devises /users/sign_in link. The problem is wI need it to go back to the root_url instead, but I don't see where to define that at.

In my User.rb I have

```
devise :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook, :twitter]
```

and in my routes.rb I have

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {omniauth_callbacks: "omniauth_callbacks"}
```

So, is there an easy way to fix where it redirects to? I've been googling and haven't been able to see a proper solution although it's probably right in front of my face.

Also in this app, we never want the user to see Devises Session#new page. Is there a way I can disable that?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

in config/routes.rb

```
 root :to => 'your_home_controller#your_home_page' 
 devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
```

in app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

 def facebook
 # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
 @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

if @user.persisted?
  sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
  set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
else
  session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  ****redirect_to root_path****
end
 end

end
```

Answer (score -1):

To do that you would implement your own callbacks.

In config/routes.rb tell devise in which controller our callbacks are:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
```

Create the file "`app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb`"

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  # Create a method with the same name as your provider, 
  # def facebook, def twitter 
  def facebook
    # Check if user authenticated with your facebook application or not. 
    # If not redirect to root_url 
  end
end
```

Hope this gives you the guidelines.